# Store global values for use in a wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

How/Where can I store some values such as a phone number or email address so I can use these values on any page in a my custom theme?

Example: I want to store a contact phone number that should be displayed in the header file of my theme but i dont want to hardcode it into the html. I would like to store it in a simerlar way custom values are stored but accessable from any theme page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) and [`update_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) to store your settings in the WordPress database. Then you'll be able to update the options using the `wp-admin/options.php` screen (you'll have to type that in, there's no menu option) or using one of these plugins:

- [Show Me Options](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-me-options/)
- [WP Options Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-options-manager/)

Later you can [create custom option pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) for greater control.

And don't forget to use [escaping functions](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/escaping-api-updates-for-wordpress-2-8/) when rendering the options in templates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. One would be just add methods to the function.php files of your theme and call those with php wherever you need
Ex: in functions.php you could add

`function get_contact_number() { return "555-555-5555"; }`
and then whenever you want to display it just call `<?= get_contact_number()?>`

Or, even simpler, just add them as unique variables to functions.php and echo those out where you need to.

---

A more complex route would be to use the options table in wordpress. In which case you would either insert it manually into the database, or run the method `update_option('custom_name','custom_value')` (which handles both updating and creation) in one of your theme files. Then you would display the option with `get_option('custom_name')`.